# Float right and left of main content at the same time

Tags: html, css, css-float

I need to add two sidebars, one on each side of the main content. Because of the unstable content (rss feeds), I'd rather have both sidebars load after the main content in the document, but still take their respective places. Is there a way to do this with just floats, but no relative positioning? This is how it looks like so far: https://jsfiddle.net/x5ezys1j/

```css
body {
  width:360px;
}

div {
  text-align:center;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px black;
  width:120px;
  height:120px;
}

.middle {
  margin:0 120px;
}

.left {
  float:left;
}

.right {
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="middle">MAIN</div>
<div class="left">LEFT</div>
<div class="right">RIGHT</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done - https://jsfiddle.net/x5ezys1j/3/ - with plenty of inspiration from here: http://alistapart.com/article/holygrail

Needs negative margins and probably many more hacks in order to behave exactly as expected, but no absolute positioning.

```
body {
    width:120px;
    margin:0 120px;
}

div {
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px black;
    width:120px;
    height:120px;
}

.left {
    margin-left:-200%;
}

.right {
    margin-right:-100%;
}

<body>
    <div class="middle">MAIN</div>
    <div class="left">LEFT</div>
    <div class="right">RIGHT</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
    <body>
    <div class="left">LEFT</div>
    <div class="right">RIGHT</div>
    <div class="middle">MAIN</div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

***[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x5ezys1j/1/)***

Order matters so:

```
<div class="left">LEFT</div>
<div class="middle">MAIN</div> <!-- should be in the middle -->
<div class="right">RIGHT</div>
```

Than, simply float all left:

```
.left,
.middle,
.right{
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to remember that the screen will display from left to right by default so need to organise the code following this.

so first

```
<div class="left">LEFT</div>
<div class="middle">MAIN</div>
<div class="right">RIGHT</div>
```

then about your margin in your css you set 120px margin left and right which push the divs left and right to far to stay in the 360px you set for your body so they go under.
you need to remove this line or increase your body width

Answer (score 0):

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
   width:360px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

div {
    text-align:center;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px black;
    width:120px;
    height:120px;
    
}
.left{
    float: left;
}
.right{
    float: right;
}
.middle {
    margin: 0 120px;
}
```

```html
<body>    
    <div class="left">LEFT</div>       
    <div class="right">RIGHT</div>
    <div class="middle">MAIN</div> 
</body>
```